# The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to change the text in a column and in return I get this error message using Visual Basic : The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.
Code :

```
Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Contacts SET FirstName ='Jack'" & " WHERE FirstName = 'Mark' ", CN)

    CN.Open()
    Dim rows As Integer
    rows = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Comment: You can't compare `Text` to `Varchar`, you need to convert... Also IMHO use parameters always...

Comment: That seems to suggest that your `FirstName` column is type `text`. If so, why? Are you able to change it? If you can, do so. The `text`, `ntext` and `image` data types are deprecated and should no longer be used. You should be using `varchar`, `nvarchar` and `varbinary` instead.

Comment: If you're stuck with the `text` data type then any values you use to set to compare that column must also be type `text`. If you just wrap some text in single quotes in SQL code, it's `varchar` by default. You would need to either cast/convert to `text` in the SQL or use a parameter and specify the type as `text`.

Answer (score 0):

The column name 'FirstName' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. I Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once.  If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in the code.